# MySQL table called DB.Table instead Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I have a strange problem in MySQL. I create a new table, then I can not make it any change. The software looks for a table named "TED.Students" (TED is the database name) instead of "student". Here's the code:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE TED;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> USE TED;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE students
    -> (
    -> StudentID int,
    -> FirstName varchar(255),
    -> LastName varchar(255)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.57 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO Students
    -> VALUES (1, Dvir, Sade);
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'TED.Students' doesn't exist
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+---------------+
| Tables_in_TED |
+---------------+
| students      |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
mysql> CREATE TABLE students ( StudentID int, FirstName varchar(255 ) , LastName varchar(255) );
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'students' already exists
```

I searched online but could not find an explanation of the problem. 
Probably I'm missing something really simple, but I do not know what is. Until now I did not have this problem. 
The only thing that has changed is I moved from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu), but why should be a difference?

Comment: Have u tried to close Mysql and tried to create the table????

Comment: Its because the The S is in capital when you created. Change that in insert it will work.

Comment: -1 for being unable to read. Uppercase and lowercase S in question. Also your insert is going to fail, quote your name and last name while inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not aware of case sensitivity:

```
INSERT INTO students
    VALUES (1, Dvir, Sade);
```

should work. Please regard the difference between `Students` and `students`

See the manual to [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

> **Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system
>   plays a part in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger
>   names.** (Emphasis by me)
>   This means such names are not case sensitive in Windows, but are case
>   sensitive in most varieties of Unix. One notable exception is Mac OS
>   X, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that
>   is not case sensitive. However, Mac OS X also supports UFS volumes,
>   which are case sensitive just as on any Unix.
>
> By default, table aliases are case sensitive on Unix, but not so on
>   Windows or Mac OS X. The following statement would not work on Unix,
>   because it refers to the alias both as a and as A:

mysql> SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name AS a
        -> WHERE a.col_name = 1 OR A.col_name = 2;

> However, this same statement is permitted on Windows. To avoid
>   problems caused by such differences, it is best to adopt a consistent
>   convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and
>   tables using lowercase names. This convention is recommended for
>   maximum portability and ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

The switch between Windows and Linux causes identifiers to be case-sensitive. [As per the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data
>   directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one
>   file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on
>   the storage engine). Consequently, the case sensitivity of the
>   underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of
>   database and table names. This means database and table names are not
>   case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of
>   Unix.